# Exchange 2007 redirect incoming email

Tags: email

In Exchange 2007 how do I redirect all incoming email from a certain domain (*@gmail.com) to one email address

Answer (score 0):

If you have an Edge Transport server, you can do this using a Transport Rule. As far as I can see there is no way to do this on a Hub server.

EDIT: I do apologise, I misread your question - I thought you wanted to redirect emails based on the recipients address, not the sender. This should be possible on a Hub Transport server as Joost has detailed.

Comment: In the Transport Rule can I use *@gmail.com to cover any email coming from gmail.com be redirected to john.doe@email.com

Comment: Yes, but you have to use a [RegEx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997187%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) to define the pattern to match. You might have to Google around for a suitable RegEx to use, they're certainly not my strong point!

Answer (score 0):

To point you in a direction maybe a custom transport rule like defined in [this](http://www.zerohoursleep.com/2010/05/hub-transport-rule-based-on-recipients-domain/) article can help? Good luck!